# How can I show Java has blocking I/O?

Tags: java, asynchronous

How can I simulate or write a code that would indicate that Java blocks a function till it has finished its execution.
This way I will be able to show that Java has blocking I/O.

What I thought as my initial solution was to make an infinite loop but that didn't work as it will never finish its execution.

my other solution was to make a REST API and in that get request would delay and return something and think this might work but is there a native way to do it?

Here is the Java code below I want to delay the method fun2() without creating a new thread.

```
public class SetTimeOut {
     public static void  fun1(String str){
         System.out.println(str);
     }
    public static void fun2(String str){
       //how to make this function wait for 3 sec?
       System.out.println(str);  
    }
    public static void fun3(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fun1("Hello from fun1 is being called");
        fun2("Hello from fun2 is being called");
        fun3("Hello from fun3 is being called");
    }
}
```

Here is an equivalent JavaScript code to show that JavaScript has a non-blocking I/O. Want to simulate a similar kind of behavior in Java.

```js
console.log("Hey");

setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("there!")
},3000);

console.log("please help");
```

just want to write something similar in java but it should block till the execution of the setTimeout() function is complete.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep(5000)` ?

Comment: On the main Thread? can you show me to block fun2() for 5 sec only fun2()

Comment: You want to block your code in your main thread only, right? This should be able to block the thread. Pass the time in milliseconds inside this method and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You can pause execution of a thread.

```
Thread
.sleep( 
    Duration.ofSeconds ( 7 ) 
)
```

## Sleep

As discussed in comments, you can sleep the thread for a specific length of time. The static method [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(java.time.Duration)) method pauses execution of the current thread.

See [*Pausing Execution with Sleep*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) in [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) by Oracle Corp.

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.of… ( … ) ) ;
```

For example, sleep a half second.

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis ( 500 ) ) ;  // A half-second.
```

Or seven seconds.

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds ( 7 ) ) ;  // Seven seconds.
```

Or half a day.

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofHours ( 12 ) ) ;  // Twelve hours.
```

### Prior to Java 19

Before Java 19+, you must [pass a mere `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) rather than a `Duration`, as a count of milliseconds.

For example, here we pause for a half-second.

```
Thread.sleep( 500 ) ;  // 500 milliseconds is a half-second.
```

In Java 8 through Java 18, no need for you to do the math to get milliseconds. Use [`Duration#toMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--).

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ).plusSeconds( 30 ).toMillis() ) ;  // 1.5 minutes as a count of milliseconds.
```